# Why execute iowrite32() after ioread32() from an register in ccp driver included in kernel?

Tags: io, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

It's in *drivers/crypto/ccp/ccp-dev-v5.c*.

ccp is coprocessor used for crypto. `ccp5_irq_bh()` is an interrupt handler function.

Now that status is read from that register, why write it again below? That doesn't make sense.

Code is:

```c
static void ccp5_irq_bh(unsigned long data)                                                                                                                                                                 
{
        struct ccp_device *ccp = (struct ccp_device *)data;                                                                                                                                                 
        u32 status;
        unsigned int i;

        for (i = 0; i < ccp->cmd_q_count; i++) {
                struct ccp_cmd_queue *cmd_q = &ccp->cmd_q[i];                                                                                                                                               

                status = ioread32(cmd_q->reg_interrupt_status);                                                                                                                                             

                if (status) {
                        cmd_q->int_status = status;    
                        cmd_q->q_status = ioread32(cmd_q->reg_status);
                        cmd_q->q_int_status = ioread32(cmd_q->reg_int_status);                                                                                                                              

                        /* On error, only save the first error value */
                        if ((status & INT_ERROR) && !cmd_q->cmd_error)
                                cmd_q->cmd_error = CMD_Q_ERROR(cmd_q->q_status);                                                                                                                            

                        cmd_q->int_rcvd = 1;                                                                                                                                                                

                        /* Acknowledge the interrupt and wake the kthread */
                        iowrite32(status, cmd_q->reg_interrupt_status);
                        wake_up_interruptible(&cmd_q->int_queue);                                                                                                                                           
                }
        }
        ccp5_enable_queue_interrupts(ccp);                                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

Comment: It depends what the hardware does, but I'm guessing that the "interrupt status" register acts as an "interrupt clear" register when written and uses "write 1 to clear" semantics.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense for IRQ status registers. They usually keep the value until software clears them explicitly which is usually done on **W1C** (a.k.a. **write 1 to clear**) basis. It's done that way that software will tell the hardware when IRQ was handled.

Comment: @IanAbbott and 0andriy: Your guess is absolutely right! I looked up the CCP spec, and found the description of W1C used in IRQ status register: "Write back the read value of *** interrupt_status to clear the serviced interrupt"